# SpringBoot GraphQL field name mismatch

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

It seems that the names defined in the `.graphqls` file MUST match the field names in the POJO. Is there a way to maybe annotate the field so that they don't have to?

For example, I have something like this in the graphqls file

```
type Person {
     personId: ID!
     name: String!
}
```

Then in my Entity POJO I have like

```
@Id
@Column(name="PERSON_ID")
@JsonProperty("person_id")
private int personId;

@Column(name="NAME")
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;
```

So, the intention is for the field name to be `personId` and the database to store it as a column called `PERSON_ID` and for it to get serialized as JSON and GraphQL as `person_id`

But graphql talks in the language of the schema. So it serializes it as `personId` which matches the schema field but is not the intention. I could change the schema to be `person_id` but then I need to change the field too... This isn't the end of the world but it's quite "un-javalike" to have fields named that way.

I am using this library:

```
compile group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphql-spring-boot-starter', version: '5.0.2'
```

I have also seen the `@GraphQLName` annotation in the annotations library but I must be missing something because it doesn't do what I am expecting or maybe I am using it wrong.

Is there some way to get around this or should I just change the names?

Answer (score 2):

GraphQL Java uses `PropertyDataFetcher` by default to resolve field values (see [data fetching section in the docs](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v10/data-fetching/)). This data fetcher works out-of-the box when the data object returned by a top level field data fetcher contains child fields that match the data object property names.

However, you can define your own data fetcher for any field and use whatever rule you need.

So, if you want a schema that looks like this

```
type Person {
     person_id: ID!
     name: String!
}
```

and your entity like this:

```
class Person {
    private int personId;

    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}
```

You can write a simple custom data fetcher for the field `personId`

```
private RuntimeWiring buildWiring() {
    return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
            // query root data fetchers wiring
            .type(newTypeWiring("Person")
                    .dataFetcher("person_id", environment -> {
                        Person person = environment.getSource();
                        return person.getPersonId();
                    })
            )
            // maybe other wirings
            .build();
}
```

Comment: This is stupid. You shouldn't need a dozen lines of code for each field you want to explicitly name the field for. Jackson gets this right, JPA, etc... why does GraphQL struggle?

Comment: You can also create a new POJO that matches the schema and convert your data into that POJO in your main data fetcher.

Answer (score 1):

You can always define your WiringFactory and provide a default DataFetcher. In this example, the new DataFetcher uses reflection to find the method with JsonProperty annotation that matches the field name. If none, it uses the built-in PropertyDataFetcher.

```java
@Bean
public RuntimeWiringConfigurer runtimeWiringConfigurer() {
    return wiringBuilder -> wiringBuilder
            .wiringFactory(new WiringFactory() {
                @Override
                public DataFetcher<Object> getDefaultDataFetcher(FieldWiringEnvironment fieldWiringEnvironment) {
                    return dataFetchingEnvironment -> Arrays.stream(dataFetchingEnvironment.getSource().getClass().getDeclaredMethods()).filter(
                            method -> (method.getName().contains("get") && method.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class).value().equals(dataFetchingEnvironment.getField().getName()))
                    ).map(
                            method -> {
                                try {
                                    return method.invoke(dataFetchingEnvironment.getSource());
                                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                                    throw new UncheckedExecutionException(e);
                                }
                            }
                    ).findAny().orElseGet(
                            () -> new PropertyDataFetcher<>(dataFetchingEnvironment.getField().getName()).get(dataFetchingEnvironment)
                    );
                }
            })
           .scalar(buildObjectScalar());
}
```